# Iterate only length times over a list

Tags: print, eval

Let's say have the following list `foo`:

```
(setq foo '(cat dog rat bar))
```

When I iterate over it using say `dolist`, I get an extra nil:

```
(dolist (ele foo)
  (print ele))
cat

dog

rat

bar
nil
```

Why is there the extra `nil` ? Shouldn't `dolist` only iterate over the list the lenght times? (Over each element)

Of course having seen `dotimes` in the documentation along with `dolist` I tried to use that as well:

```
(dotimes (i (length foo))
  (print (nth i))))
cat

dog

rat

bar
nil
```

I also tried `(- (length foo) 1)`

```
cat

dog

rat
nil
```

#### So here are my questions

1. Shouldn't `nil` be omitted in all cases?
2. Is there a way I can omit that nil (and iterate over all elements)
3. I have a feeling that this something to do with linked lists. Can you please explain the missing concept?

**Note:** I am quite new to elisp and lisp in general. Please be gentle while commenting and answering.
I actually am iterating over an `alist` and accessing the keys and values using `car` and `cdr`.

Comment: @gigiair Oh ok. I will check on that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functions print outputs twice the expected output](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18293/functions-print-outputs-twice-the-expected-output)

Comment: It's due to your evaluating the `dolist` sexp interactively, and the command you use to do that first evaluates the sexp and then prints the result it returns. It has nothing to do with `dolist` itself or iteration.

Comment: Thank you I get what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SE Emacs.  The `nil` you are seeing is not an extra iteration: it is simply the return value of the `dolist` or `dotimes` function.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. I didn't notice that in the docs.

Comment: @BenjaminPhilip Every expression has a value, which is one important factor that makes Emacs Lisp simple.

Answer (score 1):

The issue come because the print output stream and the eval output stream are the same.
If you create a different output stream as the default one, the trouble diseapear.

```
(setq foo '(cat dog rat bar ))
  
(dolist (ele foo)
  (print ele (get-buffer-create "kill-me")))
```

The print is now int the "kill-me" buffer and the nil in the default output.buffer.